# Вложенный запрос с whereColumn и where

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста, не получается во вложенном запросе сделать выборку whereColumn и where. Выводит ошибку SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  .

```
$table2 = DB::table('table2 as t2')->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
            ->where('t2.status', '=', 'ok') // <== ВОТ ИЗ ЗА ЭТОГО ОШИБКА
            ->whereColumn('t2.table1_id', 'table1.id');

$table1 = DB::table("table1")
            ->select(DB::raw(...
            ({$table2->toSql()}) as t2,
            ..."));
```

Ну или MySQL запрос:

```
 SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.table1_id = table1.id AND status="ok" ), table1.* FROM table1 where  table1.user_id=1
```

Причем если сделать `$table2 = Table2::select(...)` и в `$table1` добавить `->mergeBindings($table2->getQuery())`, то тогда в `$table1` не работает `->where(...)`. Подскажите в чем причина.

Answer (score -1):

Вместо:

```
where('t2.status', '=', 'ok')
```

надо написать:

```
where('t2.status', 'ok')
```